# Problems with exec() and variables passing to a Python Script

Tags: php

Writing some simple embedded PHP within HTML to execute a python script, which uses some loops to run the script multiple times based on the possibility of multiple file inputs in an HTML form. It works fine for singular, but as it stands now, when running multiple files it seems to repeat some, and closer inspection, it seems that the variables being recieved by the python script are incorrect the first time. I have no idea why it is doing this, it could be super obvious. All help appreciated.

```
$len = count($_FILES["inputFile"]["name"]);
 echo "length";
 echo $len;

 for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
    $dataIn = $_FILES["inputFile"]["tmp_name"][$i];
    $originalName = $_FILES["inputFile"]["name"][$i];
    echo "TMP Name:";
    echo $dataIn;
    echo "OriginalName";
    echo $originalName;
    exec("python /home/will/public_html/OrderAnalyser.py '$dataIn' '$originalName' 2>&1",$output);
    foreach ($output as $out){
        echo $out;
        echo "<br />"; 
    }
 }
```

The output looks like this:

```
    Executing...

length2TMP Name:/var/www/tmp/phpHzJFtQOriginalNamemicro_b001.jsonAnalysis Starting on file:
Input File: /var/www/tmp/phpHzJFtQ
Original Name: micro_b001.json
"nodeID":20,

firstNode:
20
Finished Finding Argument Order,
List is as follows:
['20', '21', '22', '23', '24']
Top Node is:
24


There is NO subargument of node:
24


Analysis Complete
TMP Name:/var/www/tmp/php9vQumSOriginalNamemicro_b002.jsonAnalysis Starting on file:
Input File: /var/www/tmp/phpHzJFtQ
Original Name: micro_b001.json
"nodeID":20,

firstNode:
20
Finished Finding Argument Order,
List is as follows:
['20', '21', '22', '23', '24']
Top Node is:
24


There is NO subargument of node:
24


Analysis Complete
Analysis Starting on file:
Input File: /var/www/tmp/php9vQumS
Original Name: micro_b002.json
"nodeID":20,

firstNode:
20
Finished Finding Argument Order,
List is as follows:
['20', '21', '22', '23', '24']
Top Node is:
22


20
is child of
22


21
is child of
22


Subargument of node:
22
is:
Post Order


There is NO subargument of node:
20


There is NO subargument of node:
21


Analysis Complete
Completed...
```

As can be seen here, once it finishes with the first file (micro_b001.json), it should move onto micro_b002. The echo's in the PHP show that the variables in PHP are correct, but the print's seen from the python script show it is running again with the variables from the initial (micro_b001). Why is this happening? As you can see, once it has run the first one again for some reason, it then actually runs the second correctly, then finishes. Why does it do this weird repeat? I just cannot figure it out.

(Also, I realise this is vulnerable code, etc, it's not important right now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Broken as designed) [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function **appends** the output of the command to the given array:

> ***Parameters***
>
> ...
>
> `output`
>
> If the `output` argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing whitespace, such as `\n`, is not included in this array. **Note that if the array already contains some elements, `exec()` will append to the end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements, call `unset()` on the array before passing it to `exec()`.**

*(emphasis mine)*

---

Thus your python program is executed correctly twice. On the second loop, the output from your first command still exists in `$output`, and the output from second command is appended to this.

The fix should be:

```
unset($output);
exec("python /home/will/public_html/OrderAnalyser.py '$dataIn' '$originalName' 2>&1",$output);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give this a try asap. Apologies, I'm very inexperienced with PHP

Comment: @SneakySpriggs do not apologize, it is just PHP expectedly doing the most unexpected thing.